# Do you make a request to the database on every page change for a user in order to get user data?

Tags: node.js, angular

Probably a stupid question, but how do you guys persist data? I have a login set up and it works, but when you log in, it sets a cookie with some non-important info. Do you make a request to the DB using a user id every time that the user switches pages in order to get that users information? Isn't that a lot of calls to the database? How do you persist data properly without making hundreds of calls to the database? I've tried looking into this, but I haven't found a really good answer yet.

Comment: Can you give more information about your authentication provider? Are you using Oidc or auth0 etc.Generally you can set your user info into a service and you can inject it to get data.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't make server calls (which in tern make DB calls) each time a page refreshes. There are several ways to implement authentication, where none of them would require "requests to DB on every page change".

The most common and the industry best-practice is to use a dedicated Auth provider (e.g. Firebase Auth, Cognito, Auth0 etc.), and make use of JWT tokens. Those tokens are exchanged when a user logs in, and will contain the user "claims" (profile information, roles etc.)

You don't have to go the auth provider route, and instead implement your own. But doing so is a complex and comprehensive topic, prone to many potential errors.

Regardless of the approach, and to answer your main concern about requests "on every page change": you would generally have some singleton service, which updates the "authenticated" state of the user, and stores any values you might need in the session. When the user logs out, the service updates the authenticated state accordingly. With a singleton service, each component (AKA "page" in your description) shares the same instance of the service, and as such, authentication information is shared across the application, without the need of retrieving it over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's why we have sessions and cookies. Please read about their use. These exist in your browser and can be used to remember some information. Another concept is caching. This exists on the server side. I'd again recommend reading more about cache. If you use these correctly, the only calls to be made to the DB will be those that need to pull fresh copy of some data that hasn't been fetched before.